# Extract output to excel file using python

Tags: python, excel

This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd

allo1 = pd.read_excel('allo1.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
allo2 = pd.read_excel('allo2.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)

allo3 = allo1.add(allo2, fill_value=0)

print(allo3)
```

I would like to generate the output in a saved file "allo3.xlsx"

Comment: Did you try this allo3.to_excel("allo3.xlsx") ?

Comment: Holly. Python is really that simple. Lol. Thank you! Worked!